# What are the earning opportunities for international students with F-1 Visa in USA?

Tags: united-states, international, f1-student-visa, student

I'm prospective graduate student hoping to apply for a graduate program in usa in the coming fall intake. But a major issue that's been affecting my decision making in the past few days is the amount of stipend a grad student earns. And as it's not quite a lot which is fine if the study period is quite short. But the grad program lasts for 05 years which is a big commitment.

So apart from CPT and OPT are there any other methods to earn money whilst having a F-1 visa? Is it possible and legal to work on freelancing websites/ ecommerce/ youtube atleast using a vpn?

Thanks!

Comment: Search over on [Academia.se] like [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/177805/can-an-f-1-visa-holder-work-outside-of-the-university).

Answer (score 2):

No, aside from CPT or OPT you can only work on-campus, up to 20 hours a week. Usually that would be teaching assistant, grading papers, or support staff for the university.

> Is it possible and legal to work on freelancing websites/ ecommerce/ youtube atleast using a vpn?

Possible - of course. Legal - no.